# Make an IP forward to a directory on local machine

Tags: ip, html, hosts

I would like to setup a forward, where I open my web browser, type in an address such as: `http://helpdocs` and it direct me to a folder on my computer with a HTML file in it, such as in a website. I thought about editing the hosts file, but I'm not sure what to modify. I can use a local Webserver, however I thought of trying this first.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Hosts file edited:

```
127.0.0.1 1.web.docs 1.web.webs #WEBSITES
```

and configuration edited:

```
<Directory C:/1web>
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:/1web/helpdocs/
ServerName 1.web.docs
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:/1web/webs/
ServerName 1.web.webs
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible that the lines already in the WAMP hosts config are conflicting with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do that; just set up a web server like apache or PWS or something, set its default website's root folder to your help directory, and go to

```
http://localhost
```

But why not just do

```
file://C:/Somewhere/some_file.htm
```

and bookmark that?

Per your comment below, set up in your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1  localhost  helpdocs  webtest
```

And set up in Apache or PWS or whatever multiple sites that listen for those host headers.

Per your next comment, here's what an httpd.conf might look like (after you've done the hosts edit above):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot C:/htdocs/help/
 ServerName helpdocs
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot C:/htdocs/web/
 ServerName webtest
</VirtualHost>
```

(Adjust the DocumentRoot lines as appropriate...)

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, I would like to use different words to easily access different directories on my computer, without the use of a webserver. For example `http://helpdocs` for my programming documents, `http://webtests` for my web development and so forth.

Comment: Sure, you could set those up in your hosts file and set up host headers in your web server (not sure if PWS supports that, but apache definitely does).

But, again, if you're just looking at static HTML files on your local machine, a web server seems like overkill. Use a file:// URL and bookmark it.

Comment: Would you be able help me or provide me with a link that would be helpful to me on how to setup host headers? FYI I am currently using WAMP.

Comment: See the edited answer...

Comment: Using the method provided, it still directs me to the original WAMP directory. See edited question.

Comment: Well it will still need a NameVirtualHost directive before the VirtualHost directives, and any host definitions that were already there could conflict with it (sorry, I should have made clear that wasn't the full httpd.conf file I put in...)

Comment: Added the NameVirtualHost directive and it fixed it. Thankyou for that. +1